# What is the efficient way to populate vector from vector of vector?

Tags: c++, boost, vector

I have a vector of vector like `std::vector< std::vector< int> >` and  from this vector I want to populate `std::vector< int>`, can you please tell me efficient way to do this? There might be some boost feature which I can use. I am using VS2010. Below code snippet is what I tried:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> >::iterator outereItr = vecOfVec.begin();

while(outereItr != vecOfVec.end()) 
{
    std::vector<int>::iterator innerItr1 = (*outereItr).begin();
    while(innerItr1 != (*outereItr).end())
    {
        masterVec.push_back(*innerItr1);
        ++innerItr1;
    }
    ++outereItr;
}
```

Comment: do you mean iterate over all the subvectors of the vector of vectors and populate just one vector with their contents?

Comment: Yo dawg, I heard you like vectors...

Answer (score 6):

You can use `insert` to insert a whole vector, rather than each element individually. This will probably reduce the number of reallocations.

```
for (auto const & vec : vecOfVec) {
    masterVec.insert(masterVec.end(), vec.begin(), vec.end());
}
```

or, if your compiler doesn't support new-style `for` loops and type deduction

```
for (std::vector<std::vector<int> >::iterator it = vecOfVec.begin(); it != vecOfVec.end(); ++it) {
    masterVec.insert(masterVec.end(), it->begin(), it->end());
}
```

It might (or might not) be more efficient to add up the size of all the vectors, then reserve enough space in `masterVec` before you start.

Comment: VS2010 can not do for each.

Comment: @Danvil: OK, I've added the nasty old way of doing it.

Comment: It almost certainly is better to pre size: the sizes will be local to each other.

Comment: Thanks all..I will modify my code to use **insert()**. Also instead of for loop I can use BOOST_FOREACH to avoid such long iterator declarations. Yes, computing size first and then insert is a good idea.                                         `BOOST_FOREACH(std::vector<int>& vec,  vecOfVec)
  { masterVec.insert(masterVec.end(), vec.begin(), vec.end()); }`

Answer (score 4):

You can use the function [std::vector::insert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert).

```
std::vector<int> masterVec;
for(std::vector<std::vector<int> >::iterator it=vecOfVec.begin(); it!=vecOfVec.end(); ++it) {
    masterVec.insert(masterVec.end(), it->begin(), it->end());
}
```

If you can use C++11 the code will be much cleaner:

```
std::vector<int> masterVec;
for(const auto& x : vecOfVec) {
    masterVec.insert(masterVec.end(), x.begin(), x.end());
}
```

As Kiril pointed out in the comments computing the size of the result vector first is a good idea to avoid reallocation:

```
size_t size = 0;
for(std::vector<std::vector<int> >::iterator it=vecOfVec.begin(); it!=vecOfVec.end(); ++it) {
    size += it->size();
}
std::vector<int> masterVec;
masterVec.reserve(size);
for(std::vector<std::vector<int> >::iterator it=vecOfVec.begin(); it!=vecOfVec.end(); ++it) {
    masterVec.insert(masterVec.end(), it->begin(), it->end());
}
```

Comment: I'd add one more `for`-loop to calculate the size in advance and then use `std::vector::reserve`. Yes, that adds one more loop, but it's almost 100% sure, that it will be faster, because reallocations are really, _really_ slow (especially if there's a lot of data and even more, if the `int` is replaces with some bigger type (not to talk about custom defined heavy classes)).

Comment: That was a typo. Fixed it.